# How to get URL of a Youtube video channel when a certain channel goes live in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to fetch URL when a certain channel goes live in python?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit more complicated than that. You actually some steps to do for this kinds of programs.

1. You should create a bot (web scraper) that get's the data in a certain channel.
2. Then put this bot on a server to run it constantly
3. The this bot should notify you after changes in live stream of that channel and as an option it gives you the URL (by email or SMS).

P.S. I did some search for APIs but nothing found related to your question but [this](https://pypi.org/project/youtube-data-api/) and [this](https://pypi.org/project/pylivestream/#youtube-live) might be helpful.